# Magento - Redirect customer who hits review page to product page

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

Is there a way to redirect a customer that hits a product review page (http://mydomain.com/review/product/list/id/139/category/79/) to the actual product page?

Comment: What is the actual url for a product page, is seo friendly url enable?

Comment: yes the product url rewrite is enabled

Comment: What url do you want to be redirect to site.com/seo-url.html or site.com/catalog/product/view/id/139/category/79/?

Comment: I'd rather the seo friendly URL but honestly if the 'catalog/product/view' is easier then i'll take what i can get. I've used your code and added the custom module but still no change :( - i appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that seo friendly url is enable, then you could create a custom module that extend review/product and rewrite listAction method

In /app/etc/modules/MageIgniter_ReviewRedirect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MageIgniter_ReviewRedirect>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MageIgniter_ReviewRedirect>
  </modules>
</config>
```

In /app/code/local/MageIgniter/ReviewRedirect/controller/ReviewController.php

```
include_once 'Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php';
class MageIgniter_ReviewRedirect_ReviewController extends Mage_Review_ProductController
{
    public function listAction(){
       if ($product = $this->_initProduct()) {
            $this->_redirect($product->getUrl());
       }

    }
```

in In /app/code/local/MageIgniter/ReviewRedirect/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MageIgniter_ReviewRedirect>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MageIgniter_ReviewRedirect>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <reviewredirect>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <modules>
                <MageIgniter_ReviewRedirect before="Mage_Review">MageIgniter_ReviewRedirect<MageIgniter_ReviewRedirect>
            </modules>
            <frontName>review</frontName>
          </args>
      </reviewredirect>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <reviewredirect>
        <class>MageIgniter_ReviewRedirect_Helper</class>
      </reviewredirect>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

In /app/code/local/MageIgniter/ReviewRedirect/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class MageIgniter_ReviewRedirect_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Comment: in the config, should that be <checkout>??

Comment: No.. change it to `<review>`

Comment: doesn't seem to be working. `code`<config>
 <modules>
 </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <review>
            <args>
                <modules>
                     <Reviewr_ReviewRedirect before="Mage_Review">Reviewr_ReviewRedirect</Reviewr_ReviewRedirect>
                </modules>
            </args>
            </review>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>`code` then added 'controllers' directory and added ProductController.php with your code above

Comment: Add your config.xml to your question (in a readable format)... did you create /app/etc/modules/My_Module.xml

Comment: yep and it's enabled: `code`<config>
    <modules>
        <Reviewr_ReviewRedirect>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Reviewr_ReviewRedirect>
    </modules>
</config>`code`

Comment: Take a look at my updated code... also for debugging add a die('here'); to the head of your controller

Answer (score 0):

You could place a redirect on the method listAction in the ProductController. 
(app/code/core/mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php)

Edit: Best practice is to create your own module to overwrite this controller,

Answer (score 0):

There is an otherwise defunct feature from old Magento which only requires a module config:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <yourmodulename>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/review/product/list#]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[/catalog/product/view]]></to>
            </yourmodulename>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
</config>
```

Underneath it is just using [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) on the requested path so you should have no trouble understanding the PCRE patterns.  With a bit of imagination you could even merge the above into `app/etc/local/xml` if you didn't want to create a whole module just for this.

Comment: i get the error: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '^'  in /var/www/vhosts/dev.medsupplyshop.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php on line 257

Comment: Apologies.  I made a simple typo and had one too many hash characters.

Comment: no change to the url. the thing is, i'm not looking to simply rewrite the url but rather i'm looking to redirect the customer to the product page when they hit the review page.